# Splitting the data in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, drop-down-menu, split

I am trying to display a column from my local database into a dropdown list. The problem is that I would need to split the data so that they are not displayed all in one line. I have used the ";" to separate the data and then using the split(";") method to split them. I have tried the code that I've wrote below but it's not working. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public string DisplayTopicNames()
{
    string topicNames = "";

    // declare the connection string 
    string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

    // Initialise the connection 
    OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database);
    //Query
    string queryStr = "SELECT TopicName FROM Topics";
    // Create a command object 
    OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, myConn);
    // Open the connection 
    myCommand.Connection.Open();
    // Execute the command 
    OleDbDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    // Extract the results 
    while (myDataReader.Read())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            topicNames += myDataReader.GetValue(i) + " ";
        topicNames += ";";
    }

    //Because the topicNames are seperated by a semicolon, I would have to split it using the split()
    string[] splittedTopicNames = topicNames.Split(';');
    // close the connection 
    myCommand.Connection.Close();

    return Convert.ToString(splittedTopicNames);
}
```

Comment: You really should be getting the data from the DB, closing your connection, THEN manipulating it.

Comment: Could you just return the array of split strings instead of converting them to a string?

Comment: @Tim nope, It wont let me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning just one column from the table.
There is no reason to use a for loop over a field count (it is always 1)
Instead you could use  a `List(Of String)` to save the values returned by the rows found.
Then return this list to use as datasource for your DropDownList

```
List<string> topicNames = new List<string>();
// Extract the results 
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    topicNames.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString();
}
....
return topicNames;
```

However it is not clear if the field `TopicName` contains itself strings separated by semicolon.
In this case you could write:

```
List<string> topicNames = new List<string>();
// Extract the results 
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    string[] topics = myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString().Split(';')
    topicNames.AddRange(topics);
}
...
return topicNames;
```

if you prefer to return an array of strings then it is just a matter to convert the list to an array

```
return topicNames.ToArray();
```

**EDIT**
Of course returning an array or a List(Of String) requires changes to the return value of your method

```
 public List<string> DisplayTopicNames()
 {
     ......
 }
```

or

```
 public string[] DisplayTopicNames()
 {
     ......
 }
```

if you still prefer to return a string separated by semicolons then change the return statement in this way

```
 return string.Join(";", topicNames.ToArra());
```

Comment: hmm, Your code is clear and it makes sense. But am I suppose to write  "return Convert.ToString(topicNames);" at the end of the line?

Comment: It depends on what the calling code expects and if that code could be changed or not. A List(Of String) is a better approach than an array but there are cases where the array is expected and you cannot change that.

Comment: It would not let me just do "return topicNames" or "return topicNames.ToArray()

Comment: it gives me an error Error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'"

Comment: @user123, you would have to change the return type of your method to be a `string[]`. The problem here is that you were reading in already separated data, then stringing it together with `;`, and then splitting that string again at the end of your method. It's just not making sense. If your `DropDownList` is available to you here then add to it inline like I stated, and if it's not, then return a `List<string>` or `string[]` and bind to that in the calling code.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud and Steve, My bad, I forgot to change the data type of the method. Its been changed to public List<sting>... Thank you for the help :)

Comment: I have tried passing the topics into the list but it is only showing the first value, nothing else. Would the following code be correct: "DropDownList1.Items.Add(dt.DisplayTopicNames());" @MichaelPerrenoud

Comment: No, just bind the DataSource property. `DropDownList1.DataSource = dt.DisplayTopicNames(); DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: @Steve Yes I tried this, but it shows e.g."Java" as "J" "a" "v" "a". Still not showing everything in the list

Comment: Not sure where is the problem. I suggest to open a new question focused on this problem. So more people could be interested.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28134/discussion-between-user123-and-steve)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've lost my mind, something like this should work:

```
while (myDataReader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < myDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
        ddl.Items.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(i))
}
```

where `ddl` is the name of your `DropDownList`. If your `ddl` isn't available here, then add them to a `List<string>` collection instead and return that. And then this code may now become irrelevant:

```
//Because the topicNames are seperated by a semicolon, I would have to split it using the split()
string[] splittedTopicNames = topicNames.Split(';');
// close the connection 
myCommand.Connection.Close();

return Convert.ToString(splittedTopicNames);
```

but, on top of all this I want to restructure the code for you a little because you need to be leveraging things like `using`.

```
public string DisplayTopicNames()
{
    string topicNames = "";

    // declare the connection string 
    string database = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";

    // Initialise the connection 
    using (OleDbConnection myConn = new OleDbConnection(database))
    {
        myConn.Open();

        // Create a command object 
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TopicName FROM Topics", myConn);

        // Execute the command 
        using (OleDbDataReader myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Extract the results 
            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < myDataReader.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    ddl.Items.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // not sure anything needs returned here anymore
    // but you'll have to evaluate that
    return "";
}
```

The reason you want to leverage the `using` statement is to ensure that unmanaged resources that exist in the `DataReader` and `Connection` get disposed properly. When leaving the `using` statement it will automatically call `Dispose` on the object. This statement is **only used** for objects that implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
public List<string> DisplayTopicNames()
{
    List<string> topics = new List<string>();

    // Initialise the connection 
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Forum.accdb;Persist Security Info=True");
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT TopicName FROM Topics");
    using(conn)
    using(cmd)
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        // Execute the command 
        using(OleDbDataReader myDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Extract the results 
            while(myDataReader.Read())
            {
            topics.Add(myDataReader.GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
    }
}

return topics;
```

}

Comment: can you explain the use of "using(conn)" and "using(cmd)" please

Comment: @user123 sure.  using(conn) automatically disposes the connection when it goes out of scope.  This means you don't have to call conn.Close() explicitly.  Essentially, wraps it in a try/finally with conn.Dispose() in the finally.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your help. But the other post was slightly clear. Thanks again :) Really appreciate it